# Balancing and making the references into 3 columns

Tags: multicol

I'm using the below coding in a Tex file and getting the output in 2 columns.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} \usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{1} Lobo RF, Zones SI, Davis ME. 1995 Structure-direction in
zeolite synthesis. \textit{J. Inclus. Phen. Mol. Rec.} \textbf{21},
47--78.

\bibitem{2} Moliner M, Rey F, Corma A. 2013 Towards the rational
design of efficient organic structure-directing agents for zeolite
synthesis. \textit{Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.} \textbf{52}, 13880--13889.

\bibitem{3} Freyhardt CC, Tsapatsis M, Lobo RF, Balkus KJ, Davis ME.
1996 A high-silica zeolite with a 14-tetrahedral-atom pore opening.
\textit{Nature} \textbf{381}, 295--298.

\bibitem{4} Wagner P, Yoshikawa M, Lovallo M, Tsuji K, Tsapatsis M,
Davis ME. 1997 CIT-5: a high-silica zeolite with 14-ring pores.
\textit{Chem. Commun.}, 2179--2180.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Whereas, I want to balance the text before references and the reference text should be in 3 column format.

Please look into the screen shot sample for your reference.

[image]

Could anyone suggest me how to get this format?

Answer (score 2):

One option using `multicols` from the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package; the `thebibliography` environmet was redefined to use a `multicols` with the three required columns:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\begin{multicols}{3}[\section*{\refname}]%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist\end{multicols}}
\makeatother      

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{1} Lobo RF, Zones SI, Davis ME. 1995 Structure-direction in
zeolite synthesis. \textit{J. Inclus. Phen. Mol. Rec.} \textbf{21},
47--78.

\bibitem{2} Moliner M, Rey F, Corma A. 2013 Towards the rational
design of efficient organic structure-directing agents for zeolite
synthesis. \textit{Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.} \textbf{52}, 13880--13889.

\bibitem{3} Freyhardt CC, Tsapatsis M, Lobo RF, Balkus KJ, Davis ME.
1996 A high-silica zeolite with a 14-tetrahedral-atom pore opening.
\textit{Nature} \textbf{381}, 295--298.

\bibitem{4} Wagner P, Yoshikawa M, Lovallo M, Tsuji K, Tsapatsis M,
Davis ME. 1997 CIT-5: a high-silica zeolite with 14-ring pores.
\textit{Chem. Commun.}, 2179--2180.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that instead of the `twocolumn` class option, a `multicols` environment with two columns is used for the document body. This means that standard `multicol` restrictions now apply (no floats, except in starred form are allowed).

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. Is there any automatic solution without using the command "\begin{multicols}{2}" as shown below:
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

Answer (score 0):

Atlast, after a long try I have got the solution.

I have used "cuted.sty" and added "\begin{strip}...\end{strip}" in the bibliography environment. It is coming correctly now.

Thank u all for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The way that works for me is as below:

```
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{multicol}
```

Then for the bib part in the document:

```
\begin{strip} % use the cuted package
\begin{multicols*}{3} % use the multicol package

\bibliography{references}

%\blindtext\blindtext
\end{multicols*}
\end{strip}
```